# Secure Authentication: Rails WebApp and iOS App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, authentication, oauth

i searched a long time but could only find really basic information, so i decided to ask here:

The simple thing is, that I wanna authenticate an iOS Application against a rails web Application.
I thought about something like HTTP Basic or Token based - but this isn't what I really want.
I wanna authenticate against OAuth from Facebook, Twitter and so on.
On the rails side this is really easy. Device with omniAuth did this job great.
But how shall I authenticate the iOS App with this method?

It would be great if anybody could give an more detailed view on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two solutions.

1: WebView

Use WebView for OAuth request/response.

[SHKOAuthView](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/UI/SHKOAuthView.m) of ShareKit will help your understanding.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{       
    // "OAUTH_DID_FINISH_SUCCESS_URL" is URL your wab app display after finishing OAuth authentication successfully. 
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:OAUTH_DID_FINISH_SUCCESS_URL])
    {
        // OAuth success
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

After finishing OAuth authentication with WebView, iOS app automatically save cookie(if web app save cookie), so iOS app can normally request/response to web app. Incidentally Android may not save cookie automatically, so token based authentication is better if you have to support Android app too.

2: RestKit

[RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) support OAuth.

I think Device is not the best solution for iOS Application with OAuth.
I think scratch authentication with omniAuth is better.

Comment: This solves only one part of the problem. But for Authenticate via OAuth I need to be OAuth Provider myself, or am I wrong?

With your solution I could Authenticate the iOS Device against an OAuth Provider - but I need to authenticate my WebApp Against OAuth Provider and authenticate my iOS Device against my WebApp


Example:


`Twitter <-> WebApp <-> iOS App`

Comment: I used first solution(1: WebView). My web app(Rails 3.1) is [SingSing](http://www.singsing.biz/). My iOS app is [A Cappella LITE](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/acappellalite/id370754632?mt=8).

Comment: If you use cookie based authentication for Rail app and WebView for authentication of iOS app, implement OmniAuth normally. If you use token based authentication for Rail app, see [RKDiscussionBoard](https://github.com/RestKit/RKDiscussionBoard) of RestKit example.